# What is the cause of this discrepancy between the values rendered from css and the values calculated with JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a layout that has a non-structural diagonal divider in the design. To accomplish integrating this design element I am appended a div to each full-windowed page section and styling them thus:

```
div.diagonallySplitShader {
position: absolute;
display: block;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9;
background: linear-gradient(95deg, rgba(200,100,0,0.6) 0%, rgba(200,100,0,0.6) 70%, rgba(0,100,200,0.6) 70.1%, rgba(0,100,200,0.6) 100%);
}
```

I am using an offset of 3.775% to align each section's shader at 1920px width.
This works effectively at 16:9 aspect ratios, but this is not a responsive solution. To that end I've written a small amount of JS to calculate the offset based of the shader element's current dimensions:

```
    (()=>{

    "use strict";

    function truncate(figure, decimals = 2) {
        let d = Math.pow(10, decimals);
        return (parseInt(figure * d) / d).toFixed(decimals);
    }

    function round(rnum, rlength) { 
        var newnumber = Math.round(rnum * Math.pow(10, rlength)) / Math.pow(10, rlength);
        return newnumber;
    }

    // ensure diagonal layout line is responsive
    function getStopOffset(angle, length, windowWidth) {
        let radians = angle * Math.PI / 180,
            adjacent = length,
            tangent = Math.tan(radians),
            opposite = adjacent * tangent,
            offset = opposite / windowWidth;
        return (offset * 100);
    }

    let sections = [
        document.getElementById('landing'),
        document.getElementById('news'),
        document.getElementById('specialists')
    ];

    const angle = 5;

    let styleTemplate = [
        /*0*/'background: linear-gradient(95deg, ',
        /*1*/'rgba(200,100,0,0.6) ',
        /*2*/'0%, ',
        /*3*/'rgba(200,100,0,0.6) ',
        /*4*/70,
        /*5*/'%, ',
        /*6*/'rgba(0,100,200,0.6) ',
        /*7*/70.1,
        /*8*/'%, ',
        /*9*/'rgba(0,100,200,0.6) ',
        /*10*/'100%',
        /*11*/');'];

    sections.forEach((e,i) => {
        new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            let el,
                error;
            try {
                let div = document.createElement('div');
                div.classList.add('diagonallySplitShader');
                e.appendChild(div);
                el = div;
            } catch(err) {
                error = err;
            }
            resolve(el);
            reject(error);
        }).then(shader => {
            /* 
            * TODO:
            * - Add logic to handle window increasing in resolution greater than 1920x1080.
            * - Add safegaurd to prevent resize firing before window has resized when browser is windowed/maximized.
            * - (Possible) add function to handle altering gradient color stops.
            */
            shader = document.getElementsByClassName('diagonallySplitShader')[i];
            window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
                let newOffset = getStopOffset(angle, e.clientHeight, e.clientWidth);
                    let background = '';
                    for (let j = 0; j < styleTemplate.length; ++j) {
                        let part = styleTemplate[j];
                        if (j === 4 || j === 7) {
                            part = truncate(parseFloat(styleTemplate[j] - (newOffset * i)));
                        }
                        background += part;
                    }
                    shader.setAttribute('style', background);
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    });

})();
```

I assumed this would function as designed but it simply does not line up; the variance is about 2.25px.

```
Radians: 0.08726646259971647
Tangent: 0.08748866352592401
Opposite: 70.25339681131697

actual offset: 3.7750000000000057%
calculated offset: 3.659031083922759%

pixels from percentage of element width: 72.48px
calculated offset pixels: 70.25339681131697%
```

The apparent right triangle rendered by the css and calculated with JS utilize the same source values: a 5° angle and the same length for the adjacent side, aka the height of the div.

Wherein does the horizontal offset discrepancy arise?

See these screen captures:
[manual offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy3yS.png)
[calculated offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUUzU.png)

Comment: Why can't you just apply one overlay to both sections?

Comment: Unfortunately no as I am working in a WordPress theme (Jupiter) and have to keep the structural layout intact for when the site is handed over to our clients. Regardless I am still very interested in WHY this is occurring as opposed to alternate solutions which are less elegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the discrepancy is that css gradient backgrounds are asymmetrical by nature, this stems from the variance in height in each element that they occur in.

Therefor the solution is rather simple; in that decoupling the gradient from the offset by encapsulating the gradient in a uniform wrapper, and by then applying the offset to that wrapper, everything then functions as intended.

```
/*
* align shaders
*/
window.addEventListener(
    'load',
    () =>
    {
        window.addEventListener(
            'resize',
            () =>
            {
                let s = document.getElementsByClassName('shader');
                let o1 = round( getOpposite( 6, s[0].offsetHeight ), 1 );
                let o2 = round( getOpposite( 6, s[1].offsetHeight ), 1 );
                let o3 = round( getOpposite( 6, s[2].offsetHeight ), 1 );
                let o12 = ( o1 + (o2 - o1) / 2 );
                s[1].getElementsByClassName( 'subShader' )[0].style.transform = 'translate( ' + ( -1 * o12 ) + 'px )';
                let o23 = ( ( o2 + ( o3 - o2 ) / 2 ) + o12 );
                s[2].getElementsByClassName( 'subShader' )[0].style.transform = 'translate( ' + ( -1 * o23 ) + 'px )';
            }
        );
        window.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'resize' ) );
    }
);
function round( rnum, rlength )
{
    return Math.round( rnum * Math.pow( 10, rlength ) ) / Math.pow( 10, rlength );
}
function getOpposite( angle, adjacent )
{
    return adjacent * Math.tan( angle * Math.PI / 180 );
}
```